# Command works in bash but not script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate nanopore_py3

REF=/mnt/projects/lich/stooldrug/iRep_temp/co_growth/MG1655.fasta

iRep -f $REF -s MMF064_HS006/MMF064_2.sam -o MMF064.iRep
```

When I run the script on the hpc (qsub) it returns an error log:

```
/opt/p6444/n121/job_scripts/19745189: line 3: activate: No such file or directory
/opt/p6444/n121/job_scripts/19745189: line 7: iRep: command not found
```

Strangely, when I run `source activate nanopore_py3` on my terminal, everything works fine. I've also added the pathway for the source command to my $PATH.

Anyone can help?

Comment: `added the pathway for the source command to my $PATH` did you dd the pathway to the `activate` script in your script too? What if you inspect the `$PATH` value at the beginning of you script `echo $PATH` and confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs in it's own shell environment, so it doesn't know about the `PATH` variable in your environment. You need to set `PATH` in your script and include the locations of the programs you are trying to execute.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/some/path/bin

source activate nanopore_py3

# ...
```

Alternatively, you can `source` the full path:

```
source /some/path/activate /other/path/nanopore_py3
```

Comment: Ok, edited the PATH of the program into my script and it is currently running. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1. This fixed an issue I was having in CentOS 7 with the dotnet command working fine in the terminal but failing in a bash script.